# Laravel Custom Validation: Show field data of failing record

Tags: laravel, validation

I need a way to place data of failing record along with count of records that failed because of the same reason. I hope the explanation is enough to get the requirement.

eg:

`$rules['inventories.*.activity_id']= [ 'required', 'exists:activities,id ];`

`$messages['inventories.*.activity_id.required'] = 'Activity id can not be blank.';`
`$messages['inventories.*.activity_id.exists'] = "Activity id <<< [FAILING RECORD -> ACTIVITY_ID] >>> does not exist in the system. <<< NUMBER OF RECORDS FAILED FOR THIS REASON >>> entries skipped.";`

Anyone have an idea about this?
I found I can place :attributes but this does't not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the `:input` attribute to display the value you are checking the existence of in your custom validation message:

```
'Activity id :input does not exist in the system.'
```

Though this will not get you to your failure count part.

Comment: Yes, I can get the activity_id with your answer. Need to get the count now. Thanks.

Comment: I manged to get the count by doing a foreach on errors because I did not find easier way. I am going to accept this as the answer. Thanks @lagbox.

Answer (score 1):

this shows you number of validation errors:

```
count($errors)
```

if you want to show the invalid value that passed among request in the error message, you can do this:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'fieldname.numeric' => 
                     'The :attribute must be numeric. Your value is '.$request->input('fieldname')
    ];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting the count will not work like this because there will be more fields validating and there will be more validation errors. I need to separate by field. For one activity i need to show error once with number of fail count.

I will give you my request data so that you have a better understanding.

``[
  {
    "name":"test",
    "activity_id": 2300,
    "more_fields":"data"
  },
 {
    "name":"test 2",
    "activity_id": 2301,
    "more_fields":"data"
  }
]``